# Convert long hex codes to short hex codes in PHP

Tags: php, css

What would be the best way to convert css hex codes to their shorter counterparts using PHP? Just writing a css compression script and though it may help a bit with file size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're looking to convert from one format (#RRGGBB, with 8 bits of colour information per channel) to a *distinctly different* format (#RGB, with only 4 bits of colour information per channel). This can only be done if both hexadecimal digits are the same.

You could try something simple and straightforward like this:

```
function compress_css_colour($original) {
    if (   $original[1] == $original[2]
        && $original[3] == $original[4]
        && $original[5] == $original[6]) {
        return "#" . $original[1] . $original[3] . $original[5];
    } else return $original;
}

echo compress_css_colour("#aabbcc");
// prints "#abc"
```

There are definitely more elegant solutions, although this one will work in the general case. You'll also want to add some more robustness - what if the original CSS colour is malformed, or if it's in #RRGGBBAA form?

Comment: Thanks, the only problem with that is that I would need to pass in the hex codes individually. I need to be able to parse it through the whole css file.

Comment: Parsing CSS is a *much* larger and more complex task. If you're looking to just compress your CSS in PHP, there are already many projects that do so. Take a look at https://github.com/codenothing/css-compressor.